# Which one is a valid create table Sql Statement and why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Query 1**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VarArray[]](column int)
Go
begin tran
insert into VarArray(i) select 1
rollback
Go
while(1=1)](
[column] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Query 2**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VarArray](column int)
Go
begin tran
insert into VarArray(i) select 1
rollback
Go
while(1=1)](
[column] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was asked a whil back on [SqlServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/) [Variable Array Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/questions/T-SQL/71215/).

There is a full explanation at [Topic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1002549-1299-1.aspx).

Why are you asking the question here. Have you even tried running this yourself?

Comment: thanks Mr. Astander, actually some one asked this question to me and he wants explanation of it, hmmmmmmmm but now i came to know that from where this question has came....Thanks again.